# iPhone App crashes on http post using asi-http-request

Tags: iphone, crash, asihttprequest, sigabrt

I am using **asi-http-request** to upload a file to server.
My code used to work OK, until at some point it started crashing.
The crash happens in 2 ways:
- The file is being uploaded properly and the progress is working OK, until is reaches to the end and then the entire app crash.
- When user press the "Cancel" button in order to cancel the upload.

I get this error on the console:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
and: Thread 1: Program received signal: SIGABRT

These are the 2 errors I see. No more information.

This is the code:

```
request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UPLOAD_URL_DEV]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setFile:videoFile forKey:@"video"];
[request setPostValue:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];
[request setPostValue:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
[request setPostValue:horizontalAccuracy forKey:@"accuracytHorizontal"];
[request setPostValue:verticalAccuracy forKey:@"accuracyVertical"];    
[request setPostValue:context forKey:@"context"];
[request setPostValue:[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier forKey:@"deviceId"];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upload Recording time: %@", currentTime]);
[request setPostValue:currentTime forKey:@"time"];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Facebook access token: %@", facebook.accessToken]);
[request setPostValue:facebook.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Facebook user id: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"facebook_user_id"]]);

[request setPostValue:[defaults objectForKey:@"facebook_user_id"] forKey:@"userId"];
[request setUploadProgressDelegate:uploadProgress];
uploadProgress.progress = 0;
uploadProgress.hidden = NO;
labelSendVideo.hidden = NO;
NSLog(@"Starting async upload");
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Maybe it is a memory issue?

Comment: This isn't a problem, but you can use `NSLog` without the `NSString` bit, e.g. `NSLog(@"Facebook user id: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"facebook_user_id"]);` works perfectly well.

Comment: Thanks for the advise regarding the NSString. The "uploadProgress" is a progress component. The progress is working well by the way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no code for the "didFinish..." and "didFail..." delegate methods.

Also make sure that the delegate instance (the "self" here) is not getting deallocated before the download is finished or cancelled.

Comment: I do have delegate methods and the "request" object is created in the "self" object. I think I fixed the problem, by simply changing the name of the parameter in my delegate methods. It used to be: (ASIHTTPRequest *)request and I changed it to: (ASIHTTPRequest *)req. I think it got conflicted with the "request" member (I need it to be global, since I use [request cancel].

Comment: Ah ok.. To avoid such problems in the future, you may want to follow certain guidelines concerning naming conventions in obj-C. For eg, the class private variables may be named "request_" that leaves "request" for local naming, and it also makes intent clear, that the variable is local or belongs to class.